# Adding new column with most popular string value in each row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a very large (15 million rows) pandas dataframe `df` with sample being given below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['ar', 're' ,'rw', 'rew', 'are'], 'b':['gh', 're', 'ww', 'rew', 'all'], 'c':['ar', 're', 'ww', '', 'different']})
df
     a    b          c
0   ar   gh         ar
1   re   re         re
2   rw   ww         ww
3  rew  rew         
4  are  all  different
```

I want to add another column `d` which has the most common value from the other 3 columns (could be 4 or 5 columns in actual dataframe), viz., `a, b, c` in this case. So output will look like `df` as follows:

```
     a    b          c     d
0   ar   gh         ar    ar
1   re   re         re    re
2   rw   ww         ww    ww
3  rew  rew              rew
4  are  all  different
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve it without using `lambda` function that can be pretty slow (45 mins to an hour) given the size of `df` is 15 million rows.

Comment: `df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0]` ?

Comment: thanks @anky didn't know mode works on strings too. Let me try it on big `df`

Comment: @anky still not returned after 17 minutes.

Comment: no didn't try `np.where`. `df` is around 17 million rows.

Comment: still waiting for `df.mode...` to return after ~1 hour

Comment: wow , i think because of strings , try other solns too plz , i will try to see if I find another soln

Comment: @Gery 15 million rows is a lot of rows, your best bet is to use parallel processing..@anky what do you think?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma may be yes , I am trying several other things and shall tag you. In the interim please let me know if you find a way faster :)

Comment: Sure.....@anky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.mode` to find the most frequent value and then remove values, that have multiple mode:

```py
import numpy as np

mode = df.mode(axis=1)
the_most_frequent_value = mode[0]
multiple_mode = mode.count(axis=1) > 1
the_most_frequent_value.loc[ multiple_mode ] = np.nan

df['d'] = the_most_frequent_value
```

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, you need:

```
m = df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
df['d'] = m.mask(df.nunique(1).eq(df.shape[1])) #for all are different condition
```

For a faster alternative:

```
df['d'] = np.where(df.nunique(1).eq(df.shape[1]),np.nan,df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0])
```

---

```
     a    b          c    d
0   ar   gh         ar   ar
1   re   re         re   re
2   rw   ww         ww   ww
3  rew  rew             rew
4  are  all  different  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `stack` with `value_counts`

```
s=df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
df['New']=s[s>1].reset_index(level=1)['level_1']
df
     a    b          c  New
0   ar   gh         ar   ar
1   re   re         re   re
2   rw   ww         ww   ww
3  rew  rew             rew
4  are  all  different  NaN
```

Comment: KeyError: 'the label [<function <lambda> at 0x1053a6de8>] is not in the [index]'

Comment: also it has a lamdba function that can be slow for 15 million rows of data.

Comment: @Gerry you can split